# SessionFactory in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, sessionfactory, hibernate3

I am using hibernate-2.1 and "net.sf.hibernate.SessionFactory" class in my spring project.

Now I am switched to Spring 2.5.6.A, where they are using hibernate3 and I am not able to find out the "net.sf.hibernate" package in that.

But I found SessionFactory class in the package "org.springframework.orm.toplink".

Is both the class one in hibernate-2.1 "net.sf.hibernate.SessionFactory" and another in "org.springframework.orm.toplink.SessionFactory" are same?

Can I replace first with second one?

Thanks,
Komal

Answer (score 5):

Support for Hibernate 2 was removed from Spring some time ago. With Spring 2.0, Hibernate 2 support was an optional extension, and Spring 2.5 and above supports only Hibernate 3.

When Hibernate went from v2 to v3, the package naming changed from `net.sf.hibernate` to `org.hibernate`.

Spring's TopLink `SessionFactory` has nothing whatsoever to do with Hibernate, so don't use that.

Lastly, if you are just switching *to* Spring 2.5.6, then you should consider going direct to 3.0 instead - why upgrade to an already obsoleted version?

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.hibernate.SessionFactory`.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html